# Perl: identification of unknown code

Tags: regex, perl

I have to include a perl script into a web system for my work, however the original author is no longer here and no one else in the office knows perl.
I've only first dealt with perl this morning and i'm stuck trying to figure out a couple lines that maybe someone might be able to help with

```
1] $customer = $q->param('account') || '';
2] $customer =~ s/[^\d]//g; 
3] $customer ||= ''; 
4] if( $customer and ( $customer =~ /^10\d{5}$/ or $customer eq '1' ) ) {
5]    $no_error = 1;
6] }
```

I found out that line 2 removes all non-numeric values, but I am not so sure how that statement actually functions..?
Again, i'm unsure to what `=~ /^10\d{5}$/` means.
Line 3 is the main one i cannot figure out, i'm used to `||` meaning logical `OR`.

Comment: if anyone knows of a good non-beginner-to-programming tutorial for perl, that'll be handy :)

Comment: actually, I don't think that this syntax sugar Perl 'OR' operator will be described in any fast tutorial

Comment: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Perl.productCd-1118013840.html is among recent ones, and quite good. Also check http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/

Comment: On line 2, The `[^\d]` is a negated character class that says "one character that is not a digit. You could replace it with `\D`, which is a more readable shorthand that means "any character that is not a digit". Note that in a Perl context, `digit` means any digit in a Unicode script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Accept the parameter if it's a value that Perl considers "true", otherwise, an empty string.

2) A regex substitution, eliminating any non-digits found in $customer.

3) If `$customer` is a "false" Perl value, set it to an empty string.

4) If `$customer` is a 'true' value, and either a 7-digit number starting with 10, or the string, '1'...

5) Set `$no_error` to the numeric value 1.

6) Close a block.

The `||` and `||=` operators are explained in `perldoc` [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).  In some cases, they're a lurking bug because "0" may be a legitimate value for the parameter, yet would trigger the 'or' clause, which is one reason why the `//` and `//=` operators were introduced in Perl 5.10.  Of course if the current code isn't broken in its use of `||`, don't introduce a new bug by "fixing" it. ;)

Regular expressions are explained in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

What constitutes true and false values is described in [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html), [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) and [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
$customer ||= '';
```

is same as

```
$customer = $customer || '';
```

or

```
if (!$customer) { $customer = ""; }
```

Comment: comment and question: ruby programmers like `unless` for `if not` statements. what about perl programmers?

Comment: @gaussblurinc if you ask me it is a matter of personal taste (native english speakers might prefer `unless`); not that perl programmers have common opinion on this one.

Comment: @gaussblurinc - This Perl programmer, at least, would write the last option as `$customer = '' unless $customer;` Like @mpapec said, there's not a strong stylistic consensus on that particular point in the Perl community.